# Differentiation of $\cosh(xy)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, implicit-differentiation

I'm doing an AP Math Course and I ran into this problem that I have never seen before and would like some help and an explanation...

> Consider the implicit function $\cosh(xy) = x + y$. Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$

At first it seemed simple enough, but the answer choices that are given are what confuses 
$$
\newcommand{\csch}{\text{csch}}
\begin{eqnarray}
A\qquad &\frac{xy-\csch(xy)}{y-\csch(xy)}\\
B\qquad &\frac{\csch(xy) - xy}{1-\csch(xy)}\\
C\qquad &\frac{\csch(xy)-y}{x-\csch(xy)}\\
D\qquad &\frac{\csch(xy)-y}{\csch(xy) + x}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

I've never seen $h$ before so what does that mean? I feel like I missed a chapter in the textbook but just in case, can someone explain that and also how to find the answer?

Comment: See the [hyperbolic trigonometric functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function).

Comment: Ok yeah I have no idea how to do this...

Comment: Would you know how to solve it if the equation was $x^2+2y=3xy$, for instance?

Comment: Yeah 2x + 2(dy/dx) = 3x(dy/dx) + 3y which means                 dy/dx = (2x-3y)/(3x-2)

Comment: Very good. So take the equation $\underbrace{\dfrac{e^{xy}+e^{-xy}}{2}}_{\large{=\cosh(xy)}}=x+y$. What's keeping you from differentiating?

Comment: Ok now this is where I'm stuck after differentiating
e^(xy) * (x(dy/dx) + y) - e^(-xy) * (x(dy/dx) + y) = 2 + 2(dy/dx)

i know ill have to take dy/dx in common but now i guess my problem is with the algebra of it

Comment: How do I solve for y'? and even when I do is it gonna be like what the answer choices show?

Comment: I'll be denoting $\dfrac {\mathrm dy}{dx}$ by $y'$. You correctly got $$(xy'+y)\left(e^{xy}-e^{-xy}\right)=2+y'.$$ (You didn't write it in this form, but it's easy to see that you got is this). So now  you want to solve for $y'$. From the above equation you can get $$y\left(e^{xy}-e^{-xy}\right)+xy'\left(e^{xy}-e^{-xy}\right)=2+y'$$ which in turn is equivalent to $$y\left(e^{xy}-e^{-xy}\right)-2=y'-x\left(e^{xy}-e^{-xy}\right)y'=\left(1-x\left(e^{xy}-e^{-xy}\right)\right)y'.$$

Comment: Now focus just on LHS and the RHS, ignore the middle part to get
$$\dfrac{y\left(e^{xy}-e^{-xy}\right)-2}{1-x\left(e^{xy}-e^{-xy}\right)}=y'.$$The code is not rendering, but it's good. You can copy it to an answer box below to see what it says.

Comment: Ok so from there how do I convert it to csh? Because none of the answer choices have a -2 on the numerator

Comment: Divide top and bottom by $-\left(e^{xy}-e^{-xy}\right)$ and try to make due with that. You get something very similar to C, but not quite there. A mistake was made, somewhere. **Edit:** Oh yes, I forgot $\color{red}2y'$ throughout, make the necessary adjustments, you should be able to get there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions $\cosh$ and $\sinh$ are known as **hyperbolic functions**. The definitions are: $$\cosh x = \frac{e^x + e^{-x}}{2} \qquad \quad \sinh x = \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2} $$
It is easy to remember the signs, thinking that $\cos$ is an even function, and $\sin$ is odd. You can prove easily using the definitions above that $\sinh' = \cosh$ and $\cosh' = \sinh $ (no minus sign here. We define $\tanh, \mathrm{sech}$, etc by the obvious way. Whenever doing implicit differentiation, it is nice to write clearly who is function of who. Writing $y = f(x)$, we have: $$\begin{align} \cosh(x \cdot f(x)) &= x + f(x) \\ (x \cdot f'(x) + f(x)) \sinh(x \cdot f(x)) &= 1 + f'(x) \\ x \cdot f'(x) \sinh(x \cdot f(x)) - f'(x) &= 1 - f(x) \cdot \sinh(x \cdot f(x)) \\ f'(x) = \frac{1 - f(x)}{x \sinh(x \cdot f(x)) - 1} \end{align}$$

Now it's just a matter of leaving the answer in a way we can choose an alternative. By definition, we can check that $$\cosh^2 t - \sinh^2 t = 1$$
Dividing by $\cosh^2 t $ and $\sinh^2 t $ we obtain $$\begin{align} 1 - \tanh^2 t &= \mathrm{sech}^2 t \\ \mathrm{coth}^2 t - 1 &= \mathrm{csch}^2 t \end{align}$$
Going back to our answer and using these identities, you should manage to find the correct alternative, ok? (I would try to divide both the numerator and the denominator by something, now)